# Rails has_many through, calling all events that have a certain category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, call, has-many-through

So I have events and each event can have either one or two categories, their model is as follows

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations, inverse_of: :event
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
end

class Categorization < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :category
end


class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :events, through: :categorizations
end
```

however I'm having problems calling all events that have a certain category, at first I thought something like

```
Event.categories.where(name: "special").each do |event|
.
.
.
end
```

would do the trick, however that doesn't seem to work, I've found some solutions but they don't seem to be very efficient. what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *join* the tables

```
Event.joins(:categories).where("categories.name = ?", "special")
```

Comment: yeah, that worked, I had used _join_ before, but I had no idea it worked with trough relations too. thanks!